# factorygirl rails, says "top required" in my spec - don't know how to fix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I get the following error message when I run my tests.  It says that the problem is in my lecture_spec, and that the top is required.  I don't know if this has something to do with requiring my spec_helper.rb file.

```
  1) Lecture has a valid factory
     Failure/Error: FactoryGirl.create(:lecture).should be_valid
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `after_build=' for #<Lecture:0x007fe7747bce70>
     # ./spec/models/lecture_spec.rb:21:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

My factory looks like the following:

```
require 'faker'

FactoryGirl.define do   
  factory :question do      
    association :lecture        
    name { Faker::Lorem.words(1) }

    description {Faker::Lorem.words(7)}

    factory :question_one do
      answer 1
    end

    factory :question_two do
      answer 2
    end

    factory :question_three do
      answer 3
    end
  end
end
```

And this is my lecture_spec file

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Lecture do     
  it "has a valid factory" do
    FactoryGirl.create(:lecture).should be_valid    
  end
end
```

and this is my lecture factory, where I defined the lecture factory.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :lecture do
        #association :question
        name        {Faker::Lorem.words(1)}
        description {Faker::Lorem.words(7)}
        soundfile_file_name {Faker::Lorem.words(1)}
        soundfile_content_type {Faker::Lorem.words(3)}
        soundfile_file_size     {Faker::Lorem.words(8)}

        after_build do |question|
            [:question_one, :question_two, :question_three].each do |question|
                association :questions, factory: :question, strategy: :build
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you don't have an factory that defines a lecture. It's trying to build create a lecture but you haven't defined the factory.

Adding a factory for lectures should fix the problem. Do it in its own lectures.rb file under your factories folder.

You could do the following

```
FactoryGirl.define do 
  factory :lecture do
   #some attributes here
  end
end
```

It should fix your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, I already had the lecture factory defined.  I added in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

FactoryGirl uses an `after` method with a lifecycle hook parameter to specify callbacks, so your code should read:

```
after(:build) do |question|
    [:question_one, :question_two, :question_three].each do |question|
        association :questions, factory: :question, strategy: :build
    end
end
```

See [the Callbacks section in the readme](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#callbacks) for more information.